# php greater than number decimal number without round, ceil, floor

Tags: php

Interesting problem I have here, usually I just round up/down respectively for my needs with numbers but today I find myself having to be very specific. I am working on a project of which has many dot versions. Its a web based app, with a client side application, of which a new feature is coming out where in the software if your version of the client is 2.3 or greater then the new feature is avaliable in the app, if not, then it needs to be hidden away. So I am trying

```
if($version >= 2.3){/*code to show*/}
```

which doesnt appear to be working with the decimal based number, is there a work around that anyone knows of that doesn't involve rounding it in either direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a PHP function for this specific problem called [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/version_compare).

```
if( version_compare( $version, 2.3, '>=') >= 0)
```

Comment: I never knew about this, this is a handy function. Unfortunately Nanne is correct in their answer, where if its not a 0.0.0 format it returns a false positive. Though I believe my project is actually 0.0.0 format so, this may work out.

Answer (score 0):

The version compare sounds cool, but you do need to use that format.

If you are not using "PHP standardized" version numbers, you can use bcmath's `bccomp` to compare 2 decimal numbers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

Comment: It's actually not PHP specific. In fact, [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/releases/versioning.html) has quite a detailed document defining a very similar versioning syntax for release numbers.

Comment: I never said it was PHP specific, the manual just descibes it as such: `Compares two "PHP-standardized" version number strings`, so I took the quote (that's why the quotes). Doesn't really matter what apache uses, it matters that the @chris didn't specify what scheme he used, so I thought this might help, and still think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be to late to answer this question, but here's the function I use :

```
if(!function_exists('CompareVersion')){
    function CompareVersion($v1='', $v2='', $s='>'){
        #   We delete all characters except numbers 0-9
        $regex = '/[^0-9]/';
        $v1 = preg_replace($regex, '', $v1);
        $v2 = preg_replace($regex, '', $v2);

        #   Wewill get the length of both string
        $lgt1 = strlen($v1);
        $lgt2 = strlen($v2);

        #   We will make sure that the length is the same by adding zeros at the end
        #   Example: 1031 and 30215 - 1031 is smaller then 1031 become 10310
        if($lgt2 > $lgt1){
            $v1 = str_pad($v1, $lgt2, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        } elseif($lgt1 > $lgt2){
            $v2 = str_pad($v2, $lgt1, 0, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        }

        #   We remove the leading zeros
        $v1 = ltrim($v1, 0);
        $v2 = ltrim($v2, 0);

        #   We return the result
        switch($s){
            case '>':   return $v1 > $v2;
            case '>=':  return $v1 >= $v2;
            case '<':   return $v1 < $v2;
            case '<=':  return $v1 <= $v2;
            case '=':
            case '==':  return $v1 == $v2;
            case '===': return $v1 === $v2;
            case '<>':
            case '!=':  return $v1 != $v2;
            case '!==': return $v1 !== $v2;
        }
    }
}
```